# i want to name my output xml file based on a tag value using XMLT [1.0]?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

my input code is named "input.xml".

this is my xsl code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>  
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
     <h2> product </h2>   
            <table border = "1">   
               <tr bgcolor = "pink">   
                  <th>ID</th>   
                  <th>tag</th>   
                  <th>destination</th>   
               </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select = "root/product">
              <xsl:if match=".[tag = 'good']"> 
               <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="@ID"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="tag"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="destination"/></td>
               </tr>
              </xsl:if> 
            </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

i want the output file to be named good_input.xml based on the  value.

Comment: You can't name the output file from within an XSLT 1.0 processor.

Comment: In other words, you need to determine the name in the code that *calls* the XSLT processor.

Comment: Actually, it is sort of possible if your processor supports the `exsl:document` extension element or XSLT 1.1. I say sort of, because this allows creating a subsidiary result document **in addition** to the main one.

Comment: @michael.hor257k can you tell me more ?

Comment: You can read about it here: http://exslt.org/exsl/elements/document/index.html and here: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt11/#multiple-output. Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: You could load the XML and lookup the filename value before you do the transformation. Or, you could do a transformation that returns the filename value, then do the final transformation.

Comment: @michael.hor257k i'm using the ```javax.xml.transform.Transformer```

Answer (score 0):

If the JRE uses Xalan Java 2.7 as its XSLT 1.0 processor for `Transformer` then you should be able to use a proprietary Xalan extension element `redirect:write`, as shown in https://github.com/apache/xalan-j/blob/xalan-j_2_7_1/samples/extensions/1-redir.xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:redirect="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/redirect"
    extension-element-prefixes="redirect">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <redirect:write select="concat(root/product/tag, 'result.html')">
    <html>
      ...
    </html>
  </redirect:write>
</xsl:template>
```

On the other hand, as you use Java, you can as well switch to XSLT 2 or 3 and the standardized `xsl:result-document` by putting Saxon 10 or 9 HE (available on Sourceforge and Maven) on the classpath.